# Vim warning: Looks like you've configured clangd in coc-settings.json, you should remove it to use coc-clangd

Tags: coc.nvim, clangd

I 've recently started to code on Vim and while it's not easy, it's worth it. I am struggling to figure out basic things that I had for granted in an IDE like KDevelop or VSCode especially when it comes to browsing the code by finding references, having autocomplete etc.

Lucky for me I have found CoC (-clangd etc). But I am getting an error which I can't quite understand and debug:

```
[coc.nvim] Looks like you've configured clangd in coc-settings.json, you should
 remove it to use coc-clangd
```

Of course I have configured clangd inside this file exactly because the coc-clangd plugin wants me to like this.

My `coc-settings.json`:

```
  {
          "languageserver":
          {
                  "clangd":
                  {
                          "command": "clangd",
                          "rootPatterns": ["compile_flags.txt",
                                          "compile_commands.json"],
                          "filetypes":["c",
                                          "cc",
                                          "cpp",
                                          "c++",
                                          "objc",
                                          "objcpp"]
                  },
                  "cmake":
                  {
                          "command": "cmake-language-server",
                          "filetypes": ["cmake"],
                          "rootPatterns": ["build/"],
                          "initializationOptions":
                          { 
                                  "buildDirectory": "build"
                          }
                  }
          }
          
  }
```

Autocompleting (printf for example) works normally. So what is this warning about? Is my configuration wrong or am I missing something from my setup?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I used to edit the inner "clangd" string while it should be like this:

```
 {
          "languageserver":
          {
                  "coc-clangd": <-- This
                  {
                          "command": "clangd",
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to setup clangd in coc-settings.json while using coc-clangd. Remove the `clangd` section in your coc-settings.json.

Comment: Interesting. How can `clangd`  be configured then if I need something specific?

Comment: https://github.com/clangd/coc-clangd#configurations

Comment: my coc-clangd doesnt work for `C` files..., i dont have auto-complete, but for c++ works

Comment: yea, remove the clangd config from coc-settings and you will experience that the plugin wont work at all

Answer (score 1):

the error message wants you to install `coc-clangd` and use that in `coc-settings.json` instead of plain old `clangd`. install `coc-clangd` and replace `"command": "clangd",` with `"command": "coc-clangd",` (or whatever the command for `coc-clangd` is)

edit: it is after all just a warning, and you should be able to ignore it. if the fact that there is a warn there annoys you, there might be an option to disable warns.

Comment: Thank you, but I had already tried to replace the string "clang" with "coc-clangd" and I had even worse result.

Answer (score 1):

Does it fix your problem after changing the coc-settings.json into something like this?

```
{
          "languageserver":
          {
                  "coc-clangd": <-- This
                  {
                          "command": "clangd",
```

I do fix this problem on my setup by changing the language server name to coc-clangd.

And of course, please install coc-clangd by cocInstall and clang package on your OS in advance.

Comment: Yes, this helped.